# NGINX не срабатывает rewrite

Tags: php, nginx, rewrite

Проблема в несрабатывании правила rewrite. Обращаюсь на http://server.ru/infoblock/ajax.php
Часть конфига:

```
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
                fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;
#               try_files       $uri = 404;
                include         fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param   PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 128M";
                fastcgi_param   PHP_VALUE "max_file_uploads = 10";
                #fastcgi_param   HTTPS on;
        }

        location / {
                #
                rewrite ^/images/(.*)$ /var/images/$1 last;
                rewrite ^/form/ajax.php?(.*)$ /module/form/ajax.php?$1 last;
                rewrite ^/infoblock/ajax.php?(.*)$ /module/infoblock/ajax.php?$1 last;
                ...
        }
```

При этом в логе:

```
2021/03/01 11:16:36 [error] 335#335: *2345452 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /var/www/***/infoblock/ajax.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 109.174.47.21, server: ***, request: "GET /infoblock/ajax.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock:", host: "***"
```

Получается так, мол файла такого нет, до реврайта дело не доходит.
Бред?
Или я чего-то важного не знаю?
Прошу помощи!

**UPDATE:** Работаю с NGINX около 10 лет, сайтов с похожим конфигом работает штук 20. Ошибки такой не встречал ни разу.

Comment: [Посмотрите примеры](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration) как и в каком порядке обрабатываются `location`

Comment: А ещё параметры запроса не учитываются в rewrite, так что «?» и всё что за ним не нужно писать. Ну и ликбез про регуляркам: точка спецсимвол и в ваших примерах её нужно экранировать.

Comment: @Andrey Mihalev - как работает location я знаю, не один сайт уже в него завёл.

Comment: @Alexey Ten - вы видимо не в теме, "?" и дальше мне нужно, и точку экранировать не нужно - потому она спецсимвол.

Comment: @Дмитрий видимо плохо знаете, раз рассчитываете что `location /` сработает, учитывая что есть `location ~ \.php$`

Comment: @Andrey Mihalev возможно я знаю недостаточно. Но если вы знаете лучше - подскажите, как мне исправить мою ситуацию? Я уже и location'ы создавал с более длинным префиксом и rewrite и root в них настраивал - ничего не меняется, ошибка всё та же.

Comment: @Дмитрий если честно, я по ссылке уже все подсказал. Нужно только внимательно её почитать. А если у вас возникают сомнения по отработке правил, включите `debug log` в `nginx` и покажите выхлоп лога по конкретному запросу, будет уже что обсудить.

Comment: @Andrey Mihalev возможно вопрос у меня немного невнятный. У меня есть примерно 20 сайтов с похожим конфигом, rewrite в них работает. Только в одном такое. Вопрос: что написать в конфиге, чтобы на запрос вида /infoblock/ajax.php отработал файл $docroot/module/infoblock/ajax.php?

Comment: Ну если вы считает что `/form/ajaxxph` должно подпадать под ваш rewrite, то ладно. И если за 10 лет вы так и не узнали как и когда обрабатываются правила rewrite и location, то вы не работали с nginx, а, видимо, бездумно копипастили

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение сам, всё оказалось довольно просто, может кому пригодится.
Вынес правила rewrite из location выше и заработало.